# What is wrong with this C++ code that the school gave me?

Tags: c++-cli

So this is for a school project and they told us to copy and past this code for an assignment. The school I got to is more about self study so their is no real teacher assigned to help. I asked her for help and she said she would get back to me, well two weeks later and nothing.

"String" in line 5 is an error and the error says "String Undefined".
I know thats pretty specific but this code is copy and pasted so i'm not sure what to do about it.

```
#include "MyForm.h"
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThread]
void main(array<String^>^ args)
{
Application::EnableVisualStyles();
Application::SetCompatible.TextRenderingDefault(false);

Organizer::MyForm form;
Application::Run(%form);
```

Comment: This is C++\CLI not C++.

Comment: `String` is in the `std` namespace

Comment: I'm not sure what your talking about with it not being C++ but how would I make this program work then?

Comment: It's okay to follow up with someone if they don't get back to you in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: You need to use visual studio, and the project that you paste it into has to be a C++/CLI project, not a vanilla C++ project.

Comment: @ElGavilan `String` is not in the `std` namesapce but `string` is.

Comment: I am using visual studio.

Comment: You may want to have a chat with your school about which programming language they are teaching you because large chunks of what you are learning will not carry over to C++. The relationship between C++ and C++/CLI makes them close enough to cause confusion. The most stark is probably the very different memory management ideology.

Answer (score 0):

The `String` class is in the `System` namespace. You either need to fully qualify the type (`System::String`) or, more typically, add a `using` statement at the start of your program:

```
#include "MyForm.h"
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThread]
void main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatible.TextRenderingDefault(false);

    Organizer::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```